# Raspbian Not Starting

Tags: linux, crash, raspberry-pi

My Raspberry pi suddenly stopped starting. I was playing a game on it, and there was a glitch, so I turned off the raspberry pi and turned it on again. But then, it didn't start! Here is what I saw instead:

[Raspbian telling me that its firmware was not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBtV2.jpg)

and usually it never takes this long to Boot!!
This may be because I might have stopped the raspberry pi while it was updating, but someone please help me!!

Comment: It is a one chip does all machine (at least mine is). When you start, can you start Recovery?  If not, then it appears to be a hardware error. I assume the SD card is inserted. If not insert it.

Comment: @John How do I start Recovery?

Comment: If the PI will start, Recovery is an early screen, Press the Shift key to start recovery.

Comment: @John It doesn't work.

Comment: The computer looks like it has a hardware error and needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

If your Pi was doing an update when you stopped it, there is a chance it was updating a critical file.

As a general rule, **you should never disconnect the power while updates are running**.

If the Pi is unable to find the firmware, you can try to copy across any files from the Pi installer/default image and see if that works. If not, you may have to cut your losses and set up the SD card again.
For the future, it is worth keeping your important files on a usb drive or an external hard drive so you can wipe and reload your SD card as much as you like without losing any data you want to save.

Comment: I have saved only a few files on a usb drive, and I dont know how to wipe out the SD card.